# How can i add an icon/image near specific nodes in a treeView1?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is how i'm adding the TreeNodes and Nodes to the treeView1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    public partial class DisplayResponses : Form
    {
        private int count;
        private List<string> nodesNames = new List<string>();
        private List<TreeNode> CurrentNodeMatches = new List<TreeNode>();

        public DisplayResponses()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            label11.Text = "0";
            count = 0;
            label9.Text = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName;
            InputLanguageChanged += DisplayResponses_InputLanguageChanged;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            addmore();
        }

        void DisplayResponses_InputLanguageChanged(object sender, InputLanguageChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label9.Text = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName;
        }

        public void addmore()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListsExtractions.text1.Count; i++)
            {

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < ListsExtractions.responsers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListsExtractions.responsers[i].Count == 0)
                {
                    ListsExtractions.responsers.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            foreach (List<string> l_branch in ListsExtractions.responsers)
            {
                TreeNode l_node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_branch.Count - 1]);

                for (int l_count = 0; l_count < l_branch.Count - 1; l_count++)
                {
                    l_node.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_count]);
                }
            }
        }
```

responsers is a List>

What i see in the treeView1 is this:

[image: treeView1]

Now i have another List

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListsExtractions.text1.Count; i++)
            {

            }
```

It's inside the addmore method
I want to compare each item in text1 to a node text and if they identical add near the node the icon
The icon is in my project resources.

For example in the screenshot i added here if the first node is identical/exist in the text1 add near it on the right the icon fro the resources.

EDIT

This is what i tried to do:

```
public void addmore()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListsExtractions.responsers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListsExtractions.responsers[i].Count == 0)
                {
                    ListsExtractions.responsers.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            foreach (List<string> l_branch in ListsExtractions.responsers)
            {
                TreeNode l_node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_branch.Count - 1]);
                for (int l_count = 0; l_count < l_branch.Count - 1; l_count++)
                {
                    l_node.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_count]);
                }
            }
            //AddIcons(l_node);

        }
```

And the AddIcons method:

```
private void AddIcons(TreeNode l_node)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListsExtractions.text1.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < l_node.Nodes.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (l_node.Nodes[x].Text == ListsExtractions.text1[i])
                    {
                        //l_node.ImageIndex = 0;
                        l_node.Nodes[i].ImageIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

First thing is how do i pass the l_node variable to the AddIcons method ?
Second i tried to move the l_node variable to the top of the form then inside AddIcons it never got inside the comparison:

```
if (l_node.Nodes[x].Text == ListsExtractions.text1[i])
```

And i checked some of the items in text1 exist also in the Nodes Text

I added the screenshot before what i want to do is for example if the first top node text == to one of the items in text1 then add icon.
Then move to the next node and compare it to the items in text1
And so on all the nodes only the main nodes not the child nodes.

For example if the first node is:

+-- hello world

And if hello world is in text1 then add the icon to the node hello world

also the format of items in text1 is like this:

```
In index 0 text: hello world
In index 1 empty: ""
In index 2 text: hello
In index 3 empty: ""
```

This is how text1 built

EDIT

This is what i tried now:

In the form1 constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();

            il = new ImageList();
            il.Images.Add(Properties.Resources.stock_lock);
            treeView1.ImageList = il;

            label11.Text = "0";
            count = 0;
            label9.Text = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName;
            InputLanguageChanged += DisplayResponses_InputLanguageChanged;
            button4.Enabled = false;
            addmore();
```

il is ImageList variable
And the addmore method:

```
public void addmore()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ListsExtractions.responsers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (ListsExtractions.responsers[i].Count == 0)
                {
                    ListsExtractions.responsers.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            foreach (List<string> l_branch in ListsExtractions.responsers)
            {
                TreeNode l_node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_branch.Count - 1]);
                if (ListsExtractions.text1.Contains(l_node.Text)) l_node.ImageIndex = 0;
                for (int l_count = 0; l_count < l_branch.Count - 1; l_count++)
                {
                    TreeNode l_subnode = l_node.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_count]);
                    if (ListsExtractions.text1.Contains(l_subnode.Text)) l_subnode.ImageIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

But what i get is that every node have the icon near him and not only those who exist by text/name in the List text1.
This is what i get:

[image: All with icons]

Comment: What is the question? Setting images? Add an imagelist to the form, add an image to it, let your tree refer to it and finally set a node's imageindex. Or is it finding the node you want to decorate?

Comment: Updated my question. I know how to add icons but not sure how to make the comparison between the Nodes Text and the items in text1 List<string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if that's what you want, but if you want to do the decoration during the creation of the tree you simply need to do it at the right moment, that is while you have the reference to the new node:

```
treeView1.ImageList = il;
treeView1.ImageIndex= 999;
treeView1.SelectedImageIndex= 999;


foreach (List<string> l_branch in ListsExtractions.responsers)
{
   TreeNode l_node = treeView1.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_branch.Count - 1]);
   if (ListsExtractions.Contains (l_node.Text) )   l_node.ImageIndex = 0; 
   for (int l_count = 0; l_count < l_branch.Count - 1; l_count++)
   {
      TreeNode l_subnode = l_node.Nodes.Add(l_branch[l_count]);
      if (ListsExtractions.Contains (l_subnode.Text) ) l_subnode.ImageIndex = 0;  
   }
}
```

I make use of the `Contains` method of `List<T>` and I grab a handle to the new subnodes when I create them..No need for the `AddIcons` method.

**Edit:** There was an error in the original version: If you activate the ImageList by setting one ImageIndex you need to follow a few rules: All nodes will show the first image (Index 0) in the list as both default SelectedImageIndex and default ImageIndex. Therefore you must **either** include one blank image in the list, all transparent or in the Tree's BackGroundColor on index position 0. Consequently you must set the decorated nodes to show the Image with index 1, both as SelectedImageIndexand as ImageIndex..

..**Or** you set the default indices (SelectedImageIndexand the ImageIndex) to a number you don't use in your ImageIndex.

Note the **gap** in the lines where there is no image set! You can try to patch it by creating a default image that fills the gap..:

[image: with and without gaps]

[image: gap patcher]   < === Here is one that works for me.

Comment: TaW updated my question with what i get when using your answer. It's not working good i'm getting icon near all the nodes and not only this that also exist in text1

Comment: If i remove this line in the constructor: treeView1.ImageList = il; then there is no icons at all but if i use this line then all the nodes and sub nodes have the icon.

Comment: TaW also in your answer you don't use at all with the variable il i have in the constructor that contain the icons.

Comment: @Hadar: You may want to try the patch png file I just uploaded to fill the gaps..